# prevent blank form submission

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

If I want to prevent my form to be submitted if the fields are blank and highlight the blank fields.The code I have so far works if I try to submit when it is blank but doesnt submit if the fields are filled. I cannot seem to figure out what I am doing wrong. Please help

JavaScript code:

```
function CheckFields(){
    if((document.getElementById('title').value=="") || (document.getElementById("textfield").value=="")){
        const element = document.querySelector('form');
        element.addEventListener('submit',event =>{
            event.preventDefault();

            alert("Fill the form to be submitted");
            document.getElementById("title").style.backgroundColor=red;
            document.getElementById("title").style.backgroundColor=red;
        });
    }
```

HTML:

```
<input name="post" type="submit" value="Post" onclick="CheckFields();">
```

Comment: Check out: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: And this: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_attributes.asp

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript code to stop form submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8664486/javascript-code-to-stop-form-submission)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general that is a wrong way to validate fields, but anyhow your error is the order of the condition and form submit event. So it should be like this:

```js
var myForm = document.querySelector('form');
var myTitle = document.getElementById('title');
var myTextfield = document.getElementById('textfield');
myForm.addEventListener('submit', event=>{
     if(myTitle.value=="" || myTextfield.value==""){
         alert("Fill the form to be submitted");
         myTitle.style.backgroundColor=red;
         myTextfield.style.backgroundColor=red;
         return false;
     } else {
         return true;
     };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Re-posted from: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation for the purposes of having the a static answer to this question, as the webpage may change

---

Using built-in form validation
One of the most significant features of HTML5 form controls is the ability to validate most user data without relying on JavaScript. This is done by using validation attributes on form elements. We've seen many of these earlier in the course, but to recap:

required: Specifies whether a form field needs to be filled in before the form can be submitted.
minlength and maxlength: Specifies the minimum and maximum length of textual data (strings)

min and max: Specifies the minimum and maximum values of numerical input types

type: Specifies whether the data needs to be a number, an email address, or some other specific preset type.

pattern: Specifies a regular expression that defines a pattern the entered data needs to follow.

Answer (score 0):

You can add `required` to input fields for client-side validation. For more advanced validation, you may want to add server-side validation via a model.

See `required` in action:

```html
            <form action="/action_page.php">
                <label for="fname">First name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" value="" required><br>
                <label for="lname">Last name:</label><br>
                <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" value="Doe"><br><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can validate a form in many ways. In  Html 5 form you can add required for client side validation. You can also validate form from server side. And you can also use ajax for realtime form validation. Use focus on the field.. to highlight a field that is not filled.